# Why does T-SQL print statement cause ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm calling a SQL Server SP from Jupyter, and the SP looks like this:

```
    ALTER
     procedure [dbo].[proc_Report_QuarterlyDistribution02]  (@quarter int, @year int, @group int)
    as          

            declare @total int,
            @date date

            set @date = cast(@year as varchar(4)) + '-01-01'
            set @date = dateadd(quarter, @quarter - 1, @date)

            print @date

            select @total = count(1)
            from DimMedical
            where ServiceDate between
            DATEADD(quarter, -9,@date) and @date
    and carriercode = @group
    and Category = 'Physicians'
```

The SP goes on - that's not the issue.

The problem is the line

```
    print @date
```

**Question** Why would the print statement cause the error:

```
    ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Comment: Sounds like your procedure returns no rows. Don't use print, use select if you want it to return rows.

Comment: @SeanLange yes lol. The full thing does both - it prints and returns rows. The print is breaking it. Obviously I need to remove the print statement, but I don't know why the print should bust everything up.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the print statement cause the error: "This result object does not return rows"

This is probably a limitation in the client library you are using.  Some client libraries stop looking for a result set when they see a message.

Either remove the print statement, upgrade your client library (not mentioned), or have the stored procedure insert into a table using INSERT … EXEC, and then select from that in a subsequent query.